# Does F# Interpreter (fsi.exe) also produces Intermediate Language-Code as F# Compiler (fsc.exe) does?

Tags: .net, f#, interpreter, intermediate-language

Currently I'm doing a recherche for university about F#. I have a question about the F# interactive Console and the F# compiler.

The F# compiler produces Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) code when its compiling F#-source. This is then translated by the JIT-compiler to machine code, when executing the written program.

But what does the F# Interpreter Console do? Does it also line-per-line translate the F# Code into MSIL, and then JIT that into machine code? Or does it translate the F#-Code directly into machine code?

If it converts it to IL first, then I think there probably will be an IL-interpreter because the JIT-compiler only compiles complete programs. Won't it?

What do you think, how F#-interpreter handles F# code and translates it?

Greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The F# compiler emits IL using its own library [AbsIL](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/src/absil). AbsIL is another MSR project which was absorbed by F#.

When compiling for the interactive mode, [AbsIL uses](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/absil/ilreflect.fs) the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace to emit IL in memory, at runtime, which is in turn compiled to native code by the JIT as it executes the code.

Comment: A quick grep of the source seems to suggest that AbsIL doesn't use System.Reflection.Emit but generates a binary directly to a .NET BinaryWriter stream. In places it also seems to use a custom ByterBuffer defined in bytes.fs. I believe this is because originally AbsIL had to cross compile with OCaml but has moved away from that as the compiler was boot strapped.

Comment: @Robert, have a look at the second link of my post, you'll see that it has a SRE backend, as specified in the header: «Write Abstract IL structures at runtime using Reflection.Emit»

Comment: Also, considering the number of issues that fsi triggered, and is still triggering in Mono's implementation of SRE, I can tell by experience :)

Comment: I didn't read your answer properly :§, I thought you saying it used SRE for runtime and compile time. D'oh!